# How to automatically pull data from client's webservice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, wcf, architecture, signalr

I am trying to find the best solution to build the application at work.
1) My client has a web service, I need to have a automatically process to pull data from client web service, store in a database. The data will be displayed in a aspnet MVC web application. Once new data coming in, I want to notify the current user (something like a badge)
Question 1: I have two ideas for the process to pull data from client's web service, 
           A)I create a WCF service, and host it as a Windows Service 
           B)Create a console application and get the schedule task to run the console application

Question 2: I am thinking to use SignalR to indicate users of the new data, but in the backend how do get SignalR to check the data changes?

Thanks very much guys

Regards

Comment: can you install something on your client?

Comment: No, I don't think I could install anything on my client's machine  :(

Comment: To your second question: SignalR is just used for the notification part, the logic to check whether a notification is needed is up to your implemenentation imo. As you suggested have your code check for updates, verify if the model in question changed and if so, do put out some notification to the clients.

Comment: I also think you might be putting up too many questions at once, they could perfectly be seen as separate, unrelated ones.

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: I have two ideas for the process to pull data from
>   client's web service, A)I create a WCF service, and host it as a
>   Windows Service B)Create a console application and get the schedule
>   task to run the console application

Did you mean WCF client? To pull data from client's web service you need a WCF client not a service? The rest looks ok to me here.

> Question 2: I am thinking to use SignalR to indicate users of the new
>   data, but in the backend how do get SignalR to check the data changes?

SignalR is just a mean to send notifications to clients. The way you check for updates depends on the nature of the notification. So you would better elaborate on this part to get a better advice. A common way to do it is to have a notifications log table/queue which you can check for updates, process them and send to the clients. Don't forget to remove or mark processed notification in the table.

Alternatively, you can host SignalR in a windows service with a WCF client and a timer to pull data from web services. You can notify your web users directly from the windows service. Please see this article [Tutorial: SignalR Self-Host](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host)

Hope it help!